Hide a QMessageBox in PyQt5 without triggering its exec() to return?
I have a rather complex code that utilizes QMessageBox through several states, showing results of processing of a separate thread, mostly showing different results/statuses of the process, but every once in a while (and also at the end of the process) offering the user some choices via the buttons - which actually works good enough for me.
The whole thing relies on the QMessageBox.exec_ blocking while this processing thread runs, and only exiting on when the user (is allowed to) clicks a button (and a couple of times, forcibly from the other thread using the .done(0) method).
I now have the problem of wanting to run the same process at application startup, but not show the message box for the most part, - and only show it for a couple of specific (but not all) results of the process.
Since it would be quite complex to refactor this into a "no-gui" and "gui" part, I though I'd try what I thought was an easy solution: simply run the whole process including the QMessageBox instantiation, but hide the QMessageBox right before its blocking .exec_() is called. This would have been a great idea, unfortunately it turns out that calling .hide() causes .exec_() to return and stop its blocking, which is demonstrated by the following example:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QTimer)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.setWindowTitle("My App")
    button = QPushButton("Press me for a dialog!")
    button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
    self.setCentralWidget(button)
    # one second after startup, run raise dialog quietly
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda : self.raise_dialog(quiet=True))

  def button_clicked(self, s):
    self.raise_dialog()

  def raise_dialog(self, quiet=False):
    print("some process runs here ...")
    dlg = QMessageBox(self)
    dlg.setWindowTitle("I have a question!")
    dlg.setText("This is a simple dialog")
    if quiet:
      QTimer.singleShot(1000, dlg.hide) # if I just call dlg.hide() here, ,_exec shows it again; in actual code, using this with 1 ms delay, but here 1000 for test
    button = dlg.exec()
    print("exec() returned - proceeding with code after exec() ...")
    if button == QMessageBox.Ok:
      print("OK!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()

I've deliberately set the hiding to occur 1 second after the QMessageBox is shown, so it is easily visible that as soon as the QMessageBox is hidden/disappears, the text "exec() returned - proceeding with code after exec() ..." is printed on the terminal.
So, I wanted to ask - is there a way to hide a QMessageBox (which would hopefully also hide its modality, so the main window can be interacted with in the meantime), without causing it to exit/return from its .exec_ blocking call (like QMessageBox.hide() does)?

Unrelated and somehow irrelevant (but it actually isn't): you can obviously follow whatever styling rule you want on your own code, but the standard convention uses 4 spaces for indentation. Can you please follow that convention in your codes when writing here on SO? That said, it seems that you just want to show the message box based on a specific condition. Why don't you just create a basic bool flag that is eventually changed from a signal from the thread, and eventually show the message box based on that flag?

Thanks @musicamante - I was not aware that 4 spaces indent was a standard convention; some years ago I found that it pokes my eyes/irritates me too much, and since then I've built up a habit of converting 4 spaces to 2; will be difficult for me to override that had, but I'll try (if I ever get some free time, I'll volunteer to SO, and make a live javascript indentation converter for code snippets on SO :))

There are otherwise signals and slots aplenty in my actual code - but they all rely on the dialog being shown to begin with, so it will be a mouthful to refactor that - which is what I was hoping to avoid with this hack ...

Well, the point is that QDialog automatically sets its result when hidden (in any way) when using exec(). It may not be desirable, but we have to live with it. Note that there are fundamental differences between exec() and open(). While, for most case scenarios, calling exec() will suffice and doesn't present any issues, the commonly suggested behavior (as also detailed in the documentation) is to use open(). It obviously implies some code complications, but it also ensures a more reliable behavior, as nested event loops often create issues.
